# Dynamic data binding to nested properties in knockout js - with dialog (asp.net mvc 3)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I have a table, data-bound via Knockout js. On each row is a link that I hope to display a modal dialog that will contain input fields that will also bind with my view model.

This is my server side view model

```
public class ViewModel
{
    ...//String getters/setters
     public IList<SubViewModel> SubViewModels{get;set;} // contains a couple of String properties
     ...
}
```

I then succesfully serialize this in the client and bind to a table. Each table row has a link:

```
<script type="text/html" id="myRowTemplate">
    <tr>
    <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: function(){ myModel.doStuffInADialog($data) }">Do stuff in a popup</a></td>
... other editable text fields, all playing nicely
```

This function gets called correctly, but I want to pass in the current selected row data to the template:

```
var viewModel = {
    ...
    doStuffInADialog: function (selectedRowData) {
        //how to pass this selectedRowData to the template?
        d.dialog({ ... jquery dialog stuff });
        ...
```

this is the template I want to use:

```
<script type="text/html" id="nestedPropertyTemplate">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div>
            <label>${someFieldOnNestedProperty}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <input data-bind="value: Value"/>
        </div>            
    <br />
    </div>
</script>
```

and here's the div I'll use for the dialog

```
<div data-bind=" template : { name: 'nestedPropertyTemplate', data : SubViewModels() }" style="display: none" class="dialog">
</div>
```

So, in summary .. I would like to know if there is a way / the best way to:

- Bind a template to a nested property of my JSON object
- Use a jQuery dialog to show the contents of the div that uses the template, and have the fields within the dialog databound to my knockoutjs view model
- inject the current row data dynamically into the template / dialog

Answer (score 7):

If I have understood your question correctly, I would add a property to your view model to store the currently selected row eg:

```
myRows: ko.observableArray(....),
myCurrentlySelectedRow: ko.observable(null)
```

... then in your click handler set the selected row:

```
doStuffInADialog: function (selectedRowData) {   
     myCurrentlySelectedRow(selectedRowData);
     .....
}
```

Finally, bind your template to the currently selected row:

```
<div data-bind=" template : { name: 'nestedPropertyTemplate', data : viewModel.myCurrentlySelectedRow() }"
```

That way your template will fire and re-render the contents whenever your selected row changes satifying your requirement for "inject the current row data dynamically into the template / dialog"